# Why cannot I edit TextField in VStack with a .cornerRadius()?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing SwiftUI with Xcode 11 beta 4 when confronting an issue that I cannot edit `TextField` (except the last one) in a `VStack` with `.cornerRadius()`.

When deleting the MARKED line, the code goes fine.

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3) { index in
                ChildView()
            }
        }
        .cornerRadius(10) // MARKED
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    }
}
```

Anyway, no error messages are displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `cornerRadius` currently leads to buggy behavior (not responding to touches) when the child views have scroll views or other interactive elements.

I suggest using `.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))` instead.  This is *less* buggy, but still not always working 100%.

Also, [file feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can add a .cornerRadius() modifier to a VStack itself. Why not add it to the textField in the ChildView:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on a `VStack` with a background to which I wanted to add `.cornerRadius()`. @arsenius's answer may solve the problem. However, using a `ZStack` and `Rectangle()` can also work.

Comment: @dcvonb This is not correct information.  You *can* use a `cornerRadius` on a `VStack`.  @toto-minai, I've tested my solution with your code and it does work in Beta 4.